# How to have Firebug only open in one tab

Tags: firefox, firebug

When I bring up the Firebug control panel in one tab on my browser, it is also activated in all other tabs.  So if there is only one tab I'm debugging, any time I switch away from that tab I have to hide Firebug, and every time I come back to that tab, I have to re-show it.

These tabs are NOT on the same URL, and the Firebug option "activate for same origin URL's" doesn't seem to do a thing anyway since mine is automatically in a mode which I am naming "activate for ALL URL's."

Firefox 19.0.2, Firebug 1.11.2, Win7 x64

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to `about:config` and set the preference `extensions.firebug.allPagesActivation` to `none`

Comment: Thanks, but it already is set to none. :-(  I never set that manually, so I wonder if it's related to the option I mentioned in my OP.  The weirdest part about all of this is the undesired behavior is not consistent.  If I have 10 tabs open, all different URL's, Firebug will open in maybe 5 of them (for example) when I want it open in one.

Comment: Then select `Clear Activation List` from the toolbar button dropdown menu

Comment: That does seem to work.  Although if I later activate FB manually in two tabs, then those two tabs always activate if I activate it anywhere.  Essentially meaning I may have to utilize your `clear activation list` button frequently.  Still, better than nothing!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using version 1.12.6 and I solved this by deactivating Firebug > Options > Activate For Same Origin URLs. You can use either the toolbar drop-down, the firebug icon at the top left of Firebug, or Firefox > Web Developer > Firbug.